# c++: a class accessing an std::vector of main class by pointers goes wrong

Tags: c++, pointers, openframeworks

I'm building my C++ project with VS2012 Express, Platform Toolset v100, and with openFrameworks 0.7.4.

I have a class called `NameRect` and this is part of the `.h` file:

```
void config(int cx, int cy, int cw, int ch, std::string cname) {
    x = cx;
    y = cy;
    w = cw;
    h = ch;
    name = cname;

    dead = false;
}

void branch(int iterants, std::vector<NameRect> *nrs) {
    for (int i = 0; i < iterants; i++) {
        NameRect nnr;
        nnr.config(x + w, y - iterants * h / 2 + i * h, w, h, "cb");

        children.push_back(nnr);
        nrs->push_back(nnr);
    }
}

void render() {
    if (!dead) {
        ofSetColor(ofRandom(0, 255), ofRandom(0, 255), ofRandom(0, 255), 0);
        ofRect(x, y, w, h);
    }
}
```

And there's the code in my `testApp.cpp`:

```
//--------------------------------------------------------------
void testApp::setup(){
    ofSetWindowShape(800, 600);

    nr.config(0, 300, 50, 10, "cb");
    nrs.push_back(nr);
}

//--------------------------------------------------------------
void testApp::update(){
    if (ofRandom(0, 50) <= 1 && nrs.size() < 100) {
        for (int cnri = 0; cnri < nrs.size(); cnri++) {
            if (ofRandom(0, nrs.size() - cnri) <= 1) {
                nrs[cnri].branch(2, &nrs);
            }
        }
    }
}

//--------------------------------------------------------------
void testApp::draw(){
    for (int di = 0; di < nrs.size(); di++) {
        nrs[di].render();
    }
}
```

And when I actually build (succeeds) this project and run it, it gives me such an error:

[image: this error]

I take a look at the local variables watch and it shows such large integer values!

[image: watch]

What is the problem?

Comment: it says that your program is writing to `0x00000008`, which almost certainly means you are accessing a `NULL` pointer. Are you sure everything has been initialized?

Comment: Where do errors arise (which line of code)? What's the context?

Comment: by initialization you mean `std::vector`?

Answer (score 1):

branch() is modifying the vector array which is passed in as the second parameter.

This means when you call nrs[cnri].branch(2, &nrs) from testApp::update() the underlying array structure is modified. This will lead to unpredictable results and will surely cause your access violation.

Answer (score 0):

your problem #1 is `nrs[cnri].branch(2, &nrs);`, you may be reallocating memory where `nrs[cnri]` is residing from inside `branch()` when doing `push_back()`

your problem #2, which you'll face once you have started including your header to multiple cpp files, is the way you define functions. If you define them in the header put "inline" otherwise you'll have the same function defined in multiple places.

Comment: OK. I think I got it. Then how can I gain access to `nrs` from `NameRect.h`?